# Parse two values from XML

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, nsstring

I have some XML I put into a string with:

`xmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://developer.trimet.org/ws/V1/arrivals/locIDs/4016/appID/8D8D196B90DA0E177306D3CE8"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];`

This gives me:

```
<?xml version=“1.0”encoding=“UTF-8”?>
<resultSet xmlns="urn:trimet:arrivals" queryTime="1419018749836">
<location desc="SE Morrison & 14th" dir="Westbound" lat="45.5172536692239" lng="-122.651457848479" locid="4016"/>
<arrival block="1546" departed="true" dir="0" status="estimated" estimated="1419019001000" fullSign="15 Belmont/NW 23rd to NW Thurman St" piece="1" route="15" scheduled="1419018793000" shortSign="15 To Thurman" locid="4016" detour="false">
<blockPosition feet="3781" at="1419018725000" heading="270" lat="45.5164371" lng="-122.6373635">
<trip desc="Thurman & 27th" dir="0" route="15" tripNum="5085057" destDist="37224" pattern="22" progress="33443"/>
</blockPosition>
</arrival>
```

I only want the numbers in the elements queryTime and the estimated stored into two separate variables, in this case:

```
1419018749836
```

and

```
1419019001000
```

What would parse the string to give me just those two numbers and put them into two separate variables? Thank you.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There is two way to achieve that:

1. Use [NSXMLParser](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/index.html)
2. Use [NSScanner](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/index.html)

If the attributes don't repeat in multiple node and if you don't need to parse multiple values, You can use **NSScanner**:

```
NSString *replacement = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://developer.trimet.org/ws/V1/arrivals/locIDs/4016/appID/8D8D196B90DA0E177306D3CE8"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSScanner* scanners = [NSScanner scannerWithString:replacement];
[scanners setCharactersToBeSkipped:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"\""]];
[scanners scanUpToString:@"queryTime=" intoString:nil];
[scanners scanUpToString:@"\"" intoString:nil];
if (![scanners isAtEnd])
{
    NSString *queryTime     = nil;
    NSString *estimated = nil;
    [scanners scanUpToString:@"\">" intoString:&queryTime];
    if (queryTime)
    {
        NSLog(@"Query : %@",queryTime);
    }

    [scanners scanUpToString:@"estimated=" intoString:&estimated];
    [scanners scanUpToString:@"\"" intoString:&estimated];
    [scanners scanUpToString:@"\"" intoString:&estimated];
    if (estimated)
    {
        NSLog(@"Estimated : %@",estimated);
    }

}
```

If you need to parse various values and the attributes can present in multiple nodes, you need to use NSXMLParser. Check this [document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/XMLParsing.pdf) for reference.

Comment: Awesome. I need help writing the code to do the job I asked but I'll try searching for examples of how those two are used and copy/pasting the relevant bits to get what I want. Thanks.

Comment: @Mr.Slowpoke: I have added the example for NSScanner, and apple's tutorial for NSXMLParser. Check both.

Comment: This seems like what I wanted. I'm back to my default state of confused instead of clueless so that'll work! Thank you. I think I've got it from here.

Comment: @picciano: Yeah, think so. If they mentioned the issue, that will be useful for me to improve. :)

Comment: Well I appreciate you both. It's taken me five hours but this is only my second app and today is my first time ever trying to get XML data and display it in a UILabel and I just got it. Thanks.

Comment: @Mr.Slowpoke: It's ok, everyone start like this, so don't worry. I'm very happy to know that it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

An `NSXMLParser` solution might work well since you are getting multiple objects in your XML response.

```
NSXMLParser *xml = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://developer.trimet.org/ws/V1/arrivals/locIDs/4016/appID/8D8D196B90DA0E177306D3CE8"]];

xml.delegate = self;
[xml parse];
```

Then implement the delegate method to get the values you want:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser
didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
 qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName
    attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"resultSet"]) {
        NSLog(@"queryTime: %@", [attributeDict valueForKey:@"queryTime"]);
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"arrival"]) {
        NSLog(@"estimated: %@", [attributeDict valueForKey:@"estimated"]);
    }
}
```

Since the service is currently returning two "arrivals", the output is:

```
2014-12-19 13:59:44.839 test[85905:4628499] queryTime: 1419022785305
2014-12-19 13:59:44.840 test[85905:4628499] estimated: 1419023316000
2014-12-19 13:59:44.840 test[85905:4628499] estimated: 1419024525000
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I'm still trying to sort out my first response and if that doesn't work I'll try your suggestion. Appreciated.

Comment: I'd suggest to do a if/else for "faster" results. If the `elementName` is `resultSet`, then it won't be `arrival`. Small optimization, I think.